# hibernate createQuery bug?

Tags: java, hibernate, caching, jakarta-ee, jpa

Is any way to remove cache for a specific named query? I don't really want to remove for all queries... Or is there any other workaround?

It is not working even if I am using the normal Query class...

I am using hibernate 3.6, glassfish 3.1.1, this is an java ee application (code from ejb module)

I have something like this:

```
public User getUserByName(String username) {
    try {
        return (User) em.createNamedQuery("User.getUserByName").setParameter("username", username).getSingleResult();
    } catch (NoResultException e) {
        return null;
    }
}
//...
if(getUserByName(entity.getUsername()!=null) {
    em.persist(entity);
}
//...
// username added in database (checked)
if(getUserByName(entity.getUsername())==null) {
    //something else
}
```

the second time I use "getUserByName" is again.. null... why?

I am thinking it's the cache module(because if I set my provider to eclipselink it's working as it should)...

I am using hibernate for it's search..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With EclipseLink you can do this:

```
 Query query = em.createNamedQuery("Users.findByUsername");
 query.setHint("javax.persistence.cache.storeMode", "REFRESH");
```

For hibernate the hint is:
     `org.hibernate.cacheMode`  "Override the cache mode for this query ( eg. CacheMode.REFRESH )"
For further reading and understanding: [old article](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t48846.html)

Comment: You're welcome :) Anyway here;s the rference for hibernate query hints: [link](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/entitymanager/reference/en/html/objectstate.html#d0e1215)